# Postbuild event RegServer VisualStudio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, com, post-build-event

Recently I migrated a C++ COM server project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012. Apparently all went well except the postbuild event, which is

```
"$(TargetPath)" /RegServer
```

to register the COM server EXE. It's giving me the following output:

```
error MSB3073: The command ""D:\MVo\Phoenix2 VS2012\20_SOFTWARE\SRC\Debug\Phoenix2CMM.exe" /RegServer
:VCEnd" terminated with code -2147024891
```

When the quotation marks are left out, it's exiting with code 9009.

Strang enough, when I run the same statement in the cmd window, no error occurs, regardless of whether it's run as admin or not. The posbuild has not issued a warning or error in VS2008. What's happening?

Comment: `-2147024891` = `0x80070005` = `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` "Access is denied.". Start your VS IDE as Administrator.

Comment: I tried that; the code is -2147312566 then. Where can I look up these return codes?

Comment: [`-2147312566` = `0x80029C4A` = `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY` "Error loading type library/DLL."](http://alax.info/blog/1383). You seem to have made a step forward, now the issue is related to your project (type library fell away from resource script?).

Comment: It works, thanks! Seems that during migration, the MIDL options got messed up a little, and so the TLB of the project wasn't there.